# Pass value from Ampscript to SSJS Sleep function

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

I have ampscript value which defines how many milliseconds the function should delay the process but can I pass that 'ms' value from ampscript to sleep(?). Below is my script

```
%%[
var @ms
set @ms="6000"
]%%

<script runat=server>
function sleep(milliseconds) { 
  var start = new Date().getTime(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) { 
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break; 
    } 
  } 
} 

sleep(6000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SSJS part, use `Variable.GetValue`

```
var milliseconds = Variable.GetValue("@ms")
```

in the opposite direction, it works with SetValue.
See docs for each:
[GetValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_utilitiesVariableGetValue.htm), [SetValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_utilitiesVariableSetValue.htm)

As well as more examples:

https://sfmcgeeks.com/2020/07/22/ampscript-to-ssjs-and-back-again/

Comment: I am not very well versed with SSJS so I am not sure if you are suggesting something like below but I tried it didnt work
`<script runat="server"> Platform.Load('Core','1'); var milliseconds = Variable.GetValue("@ms") function sleep(milliseconds) { var start = new Date().getTime(); for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) { if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){ break; } } } sleep(milliseconds); </script>`

Comment: Hi, that's probably because you need to make JS understand that milliseconds is an integer. 1) in AMPScript try `set @ms= 6000` without double quotes. If that alone doesn't help, then in SSJS force the value to integer like `var milliseconds = parseInt(Variable.GetValue("@ms"))`.